# How to call an ACF variable with php to replace a nested html element?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the repeater field of Wordpress' advanced custom fields to make the following content dynamic on my site.

[Image of how the content looks while marked up statically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d2Np.png)

This is how I have marked up the content using plain html.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>A few general rules of thumb</h2>
   <p><span>1.</span>Hallways and transitional spaces are best painted...</p>
   <p><span>2.</span>It is best to keep expensive furnishings...</p>
   <p><span>3.</span>If you want furnishings and accessories...</p>
   <p><span>4.</span>Neutral furnishings and accessories?</p>
</div>
```

The paragraphs have been styled by setting their display to flex so that the span (number) is on the left and the paragraph is on the right.

This is how my code now looks with PHP.

```
<div class="container">

 <h2><?php echo $container3title['title'];?></h2>
        
     <?php
       // Check rows existexists.
       if(have_rows('rules')):
       // Loop through rows.
       while(have_rows('rules')) : the_row();
    
       // Load sub field value.
       $ruleNumber = get_sub_field('ruleNumber');
       $ruleDetails = get_sub_field('ruleDetails');
    
       // Do something...
       echo '<span>' . $ruleNumber . '</span>';
       echo '<p>' . $ruleDetails . '</p>';
    
       // End loop.
       endwhile;
    
       // No value.
       else :
       // Do something...
       endif;
     ?>
    </div>
```

The problem is that I do not know how to echo the php so that the paragraphs aren't displayed as two block elements that are stacked on top of one another. I want it to be marked up the same way as I have marked it up using plain html so that my CSS will style it accordingly.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
echo '<p>' '<span>' . $ruleNumber . '</span>'; . $ruleDetails . '</p>';
```

Can someone please tell me how to put this together correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just store the span in a variable and concatenate it in:

```php
$span = '<span>' . esc_html($ruleNumber) . '</span>';
echo '<p>' . $span . esc_html($ruleDetails) . '</p>';
```

I threw some escapes in there, too. It is generally recommended to always escape user-generated input when outputting, just in case. And even though you might “know” that the number is always numeric, it doesn’t really hurt to escape it anyway, and it makes it easier to scan for unescaped values.

Comment: I would note that what you are doing can be done semantically with just CSS and an ordered list which would help with the accessibility: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/gOzXRwq